# searchview.setonquerytextlistener() type mismatch in Navigation Fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

I'm getting a "type mismatch required OnQueryTextListener!" error when trying to implement searchview in Kotlin in a Navigation Fragment.  I've searched as many samples and stackoverflow questions as I could and everything says my code should be correct.  Note that my searchview is PERSISTANT (not part of the menu), so I cannot do a menu.finditem.

[image]

Here is my HomeFragment code :

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    println("***************** Home Fragment *******************")

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            // task HERE
            return false
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

and the layout code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/materialBackgroundGrey">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:queryBackground="@null">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Search"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
```

Comment: You may want to use `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` both in the layout and in any `import` statement in your fragment, and see if that helps. There are two `SearchView` widgets (framework and AppCompat), and it is possible that you are winding up mixing-and-matching these.

Comment: Yes, that was it!  I was using SearchView in my layout instead of androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two `SearchView` widgets:

- `android.widget.SearchView`
- `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`

These fill the same role but are not compatible, and their nested interfaces, like `OnQueryTextListener`, are not compatible.

Make sure that you use the same one both in resources (such as your layout) and in any `import` statements. If you are using AppCompat, you probably want `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`.

Answer (score 0):

try using either

```
import android.widget.SearchView
```

or

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
```

but note only one at a time !!